# Potential barrier in diode

Tags: circuit-analysis, batteries, diodes

[image]

We know that a certain potential barrier develops across the \$p-n\$ junction which is \$V_{AB}\$ and when a battery is connected, it allows current to flow through it given it surpasses the knee voltage. But as shown in the figure, the circuit has no resistance till \$A\$, so the potential at \$A\$ should be equal to that of the positive terminal of battery. Similarly the potential of \$B\$ is equal to the negative terminal of battery. Now, suppose the diode is a silicon diode. So, the barrier potential which is potential difference between \$A\$ and \$B\$ is \$V_{AB}=0.7\$. Now suppose we connect an external voltage of any magnitude, say \$20V\$. So, the potential at \$A\$ should be \$20\$ and that of \$B\$ should be \$0\$. Hence, potential difference between \$A\$ and \$B\$ is \$20V\$. How can \$0.7=20\$? Surely we could have applied an external voltage of any magnitude apart from \$0.7\$ but then we are getting two different values of \$V_{AB}\$. How is it possible?

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=diode%20potential

Answer (score 1):

You've made a few idealizations and simplifications and have correctly confirmed that if your supply is an ideal voltage source, your wires are ideal, and your P-N junction is idealized as a constant voltage drop, you obtain an inconsistent result. This simply suggests that your models must be made more accurate to better model the scenario which you want to model.

A natural first choice here is to use the Shockley Equation model:

$$I_D = I_S\cdot e^{\frac{V_{AB}}{nV_T}} - 1$$

where \$I_S\$ is a consequence of device construction/geometry, \$n\$ is a consequence of material physics, and \$V_T\$ [depends on the temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_constant#The_thermal_voltage). This equation [follows from the exponential behavior of recombination/generation of electron-hole pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shockley_diode_equation#Derivation).

If you inspect this equation, you can see that applying a high external voltage \$V_{AB}\$ of 20 volts leads to an exponentially massive current flowing. For example, if \$n=1\$ and we were at room temperature, the current at \$V_{AB} = 20 \text{V}\$ is *modeled* as being [10<sup>322</sup> times greater](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=e%5E%28%2820+V+-+0.7+V%29+%2F+26+mV%29&assumption=%7B%22C%22%2C+%22V%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%22Unit%22%7D) than the current for V_AB = 0.7 V.

This leads to a second round of questions - if your diode's \$I_S\$ was 1 pA and n = 1, the current would be 500 mA at 0.7 V and room temperature, and a whopping 10^322 amperes at 20 V and room temperature. This absurd result suggests that the model we have is no longer a good model for reality and needs to be extended further.

We extend the model with some intrinsic/parasitic resistances:

- A practical voltage source will have a non-zero output impedance and/or a current limit
- Practical wires will have an ohmic impedance
- Real-world diodes will have ohmic behavior at the metal-semiconductor junctions and in the semiconductor bulk itself

We can lump these together as a term \$R_{ser}\$ measured in ohms, and extend the Shockley Equation to create an overall I-V characteristic of our circuit:

$$V = n V_T \log\left(\frac{I_D}{I_S} + 1\right) + I_DR_{ser}$$

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQrXI8m.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now, you have a more adequate model that incorporates both the logarithmic nature of diodes, *and* the series resistances that exist in reality.

If the parasitic series resistances are high enough, then the current modeled by the Shockley Equation will induce voltage drops, limiting the diode voltage to around 0.7ish volts (the variation is small because the voltage is logarithmic with respect to the current) and limiting the current throughout the circuit.

For example, suppose again that \$I_s\$ = 1 pA, n = 1 and we're at room temperature. If the applied voltage is 20 V and the total series resistance (including wires and power supply) is 10 ohms, the current is [just shy of 2 A](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+0.026+*+ln%28x+%2F+1e-12%29+%2B+%28x+*+10%29++%3D+20), which I can imagine a power diode being able to handle.

If the parasitic resistances aren't high enough, then the current will be large enough to melt and destroy the diode. In that scenario, a circuit model won't be adequate - the now-molten diode stops being electronics and starts being electrohydrodynamics/metallurgy.

e.g. Suppose that the series resistance were instead 10 milliohms. Solving the same equation gets us a current of nearly 2000 amperes, which would easily melt or vaporize many diodes.